# Splitting a String built from a char array

Tags: java, string, buffer

I'm trying to split a specific String of the format

```
0001,0004,dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss,01,value01,value02;
```

in order to extract and save `value01` and `value02`. How can I do this?

Here is what i tried so far:

```
//buffer contains a String like: "0001,0004,dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss,01,18,750"
String string = new String(buffer,0,len);

String[] parts = string.split(",");

String temp = parts[5];
String lum = parts[6];
System.out.print(temp);
System.out.print(lum);
```

With this code I get ArrayIndexOutofBounds when running the program in Netbeans.
[Image of error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfWTP.jpg)

Also tried this method:

```
//buffer contains a String like: "0001,0004,dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss,01,18,750"
String s= new String(buffer,0,len);

String aux = s + ",";
String[] dados = aux.split(",");          
float valor1 = Float.parseFloat(dados[5]);
float valor2 = Float.parseFloat(dados[6]);
System.out.print(aux);
```

Comment: If i understand this correctly your question is: How do i split the **0001,0004,dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss,01,value01,value02;** string. All the other code (reading the string etc.) is unnecessary information!

Comment: Yes that's it. Sorry if the introduction is too long but I thought i would give insight on what exactly I'm doing so it's easier to get help.

Comment: no problem, i'll edit your post to make it a bit more concisely

Comment: FYI, you should always specify a charset when decoding the string rather than rely on system default charset, which varies.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
String temp = parts[5];
String lum = parts[6];
```

Should be this:

```
String temp = parts[4];
String lum = parts[5];
```

Remember that [arrays in Java are zero-based](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). So if you do this:

```
String[] parts = "0001,0004,dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss,01,value01,value02".split(",");
```

Then "0001" would be in `parts[0]`, "0004" in `parts[1]`, "value01" in `parts[4]` etc.

Comment: I get error with that aswell. java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at wasp.Wasp$SerialReader.run(Wasp.java:85)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Maybe `len` is zero, or `buffer` is actually empty or does not contain what you think it does.

Comment: System.out.print(new String(buffer,0,len)); -> Comes out the string like I'm expecting. http://prntscr.com/e89qpp

Comment: Look, this is not a long routine where errors can hide. It's just 4 lines of very basic Java and they work flawlessly: http://prntscr.com/e89wf4 So either your code is not as shown in your question, or you made a typo when applying the solutions, or there's something else you're hiding from us.

Answer (score 0):

Achieving what you're trying to do is acutally pretty easy.

Assuming that your string really always looks like: 

`0001,0004,dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss,01,value01,value02;`

Just cut off the start of the string which you don't need and extract the values afterwards:

```
// This can be done in hundreds of ways, for the sake of simplicity i'll use substring
String s ="0001,0004,dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss,01,value01,value02;";
String cutOff = s.substring(31, s.length()-1);
String[] results = cutOff.split(",");
```

Comment: this looks like a very fragile solution. you should not be relying on an exact length of the preceding elements.

Comment: I get a different error now: Code:[link]http://prntscr.com/e89bwv[/link] Error: [link]http://prntscr.com/e89c9p[/link]

Answer (score 0):

please find below code. It has just a bit modification in Andrew's code. Since we are storing the string after splitting into a String array and it's obvious that array index starts with 0. That's why in order to get value01 and value02, we should use index 4 and 5.

```
public class JavaApplication1
 {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String str="0001,0004,dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss,01,value01,value02";
    String [] strArr=str.split(",");
    String temp=strArr[4];
    String lum=strArr[5];
    System.out.println(temp);
    System.out.println(lum);
 }   
}
```

[image: Please find the output in the image]